# chromium checkout build: Could not find Ninja

Tags: build, chromium, ninja

Trying to build webview for android in the docker container from ubuntu 18.04.

Do everything according to [instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/build-instructions.md) and last version is built okay with command:

```
autoninja -C out/Default system_webview_apk
```

But I need an older version. So I do:

```
git checkout 80.0.3987.99 -b 80-version
```

After that run sync:

```
gclient sync
```

And it also by default runs hooks after sync. Then again I start build with the same cmd:

```
autoninja -C out/Default system_webview_apk
```

But this time on checkout build it gives me error, which I can't fix for hours:

```
user@0bb1627b6f62:~/workdir/chromium/src$ autoninja -c out/Default/ system_webview_apk
depot_tools/ninja.py: Could not find Ninja in the third_party of the current project, nor in your PATH.
Please take a following action to install Ninja.
- If your project has DEPS, Add a CIPD Ninja dependency to DEPS.
- Otherwise, add Ninja to your PATH *after* depot_tools.
```

But when I switch again to the `main` branch, do sync, it is built fine!

What I do wrong? `gn args` runs okay in both cases.

On the `main` branch there is `src/third_party/ninja/`. On the checkout branch after `gclient sync` this folder disappears. Before sync `autoninja` run gives error `unknown function` because ninja's version doesn't correspond to the checkout version.

Comment: Do you have `depot_tools` installed? It's required too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it turned out that for some reason sync doesn't fetch ninja for my checkout even with `gclient sync --with_branch_heads` command. And I was confused by

> Ninja is included in depot_tools so there's nothing to install.

from [chromium docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/56.0.2924.56/docs/ninja_build.md). Moreover I thought that ninja version should correspond to my chromium checkout, but as far as I found out it concerns with `gn` tool only.

So, my solution was just to add to my docker file

```
apt install ninja-build
```

and every checkout started to build with no problem.

Comment: Herman: anyway to do this without docker?

Comment: @user386093 if you're building chromium in your system without using a docker container, then you just need to install `ninja-build` in your system. Run the same command as above in your terminal. But it might be different if you're using other Linux distributions than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you depot_tools not match you chromium source , check out the last log date of chromium ,the switch to the depot_tools dir,find a laster commit near the chromium source , checkout to  this commit,return to ninjia ,every thing is ok.

Comment: afei:

Can you describe what to do from the command-line? I'm now getting this message about Ninja not found. . . 

How do I do these steps:
 1. check out the last log date of chromium *(is that done within the src directory? and how?)*
 2. then switch to the depot_tools dir ~ not a problem, I can do that.
 3. find a laster commit near the chromium source *(I don't know how to even start on this one)*
 4. checkout to this commit *(how do I do this?)*

I'm comfortable with the command-line but I need some for information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1: git log in the chromium dir , find the last date ,ex :Date:   Mon Oct 4 10:02:51 2021
2: swtich to the depot_tools dri
3: git log --since="2021-10-01" --until="2021-10-30"; then find a commit id near the first step date, ex : 0f5bd4fd474cb63bad0c1a3a2c1e0eff9ba5f30a
4. git checkout 0f5bd4fd474cb63bad0c1a3a2c1e0eff9ba5f30a